# Android ShareProvider shows only Android-System entry

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to add a share actionbar item to my App. In the sherlock example it looks like that:

[image: Actionbar from sherlock action bar]

But when I use this code in my app:

```
public static void attachShareItemToMenu(Menu menu, String title, String url) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_share);
    ShareActionProvider provider = (ShareActionProvider)item.getActionProvider();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
    Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

    provider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
    provider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
}
```

It looks like that:

[image: Sherlock actionbar]

If I click the item it opens the default share intent. I don't understand why it looks like that because the code is not much different from the [example code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ShareActionProviders.java).

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `createChooser()` line. You do not need it. What the `ShareActionProvider` is showing is the chooser itself.

Comment: @schlingel: You're probably not the only one encountering that, copying or converting code that used to force a chooser for use with `startActivity()`. It'd be nice if `ShareActionProvider` were smart about this, so I filed a feature request: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60281